# How to remove an element based on some property using typescript in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to remove an element from an array based on its any property that can be its key, name or email or something else it can be.

**Html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let person of persons;" (click)="remove(person.key)">
  <td>{{person.key}}</td>
  <td>{{person.name}}</td>
  <td>{{person.email}}</td>
</tr>
```

**typescript**

```
persons = [
{ key: 1, name: 'Mr.sohail', email: 'sohail@tee.com' },
{ key: 2, name: 'Mr.Farhan', email: 'farhan@tee.com' },
{ key: 3, name: 'Mr.Fida', email: 'fida@tee.com' },
{ key: 4, name: 'Mr.Liaqat', email: 'liaqat@tee.com' },
{ key: 5, name: 'Mr.Abdullah', email: 'abdullah@tee.com' },
{ key: 6, name: 'Mr.Ubaid', email: 'ubaid@tee.com' },
{ key: 7, name: 'Mr.Wasif', email: 'wasif@tee.com' }
]
```

**remove method** to remove an element based on key property
but it removes based on index.

```
remove(key) {
console.log(key);
this.data.persons.splice(key, 1);
}
```

Please let me know the required changes to apply

Thanks

Comment: What is your question? You already did it correctly

Comment: I want to remove it on property bases, not on an index bases

Comment: As I can clearly see `key` is unique property of element. Still I'm wondering, what wrong you see with this answer..

Comment: Now I have updated my question

Comment: title of my question is already showing that I need to remove it on some property base, not an index base

Comment: It wasn't clear for me, so thought its better to be asking rather than adding answer and keep on correcting it. Would you mind to look at mine answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 removeByPropertyName(propertyName: string, value: any): void {
    let indexToRemove = persons.findIndex(p => p[propertyName] === value);
    if (indexToRemove !== -1)
        this.remove(indexToRemove);
    else
        console.log('Not found!');
 }
```

To remove by key, you can use the method as

```
removeByPropertyName('key', 10);
```

To remove by name,

```
removeByPropertyName('name', 'somename');
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want to delete element from an collection based on dynamic `key`(assuming it should be unique). You could consider passing two parameter for your `remove` function, `object` and `propName`

```
<tr *ngFor="let person of persons;" (click)="remove(person,'key')">
  <td>{{person.key}}</td>
  <td>{{person.name}}</td>
  <td>{{person.email}}</td>
</tr>

remove(person, propName){
   this.persons = this.persons.filter(p => p[propName] !== person[propName])
}
```

[**Demo Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ap9hdn?file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `filter` function. Also, i think it should be `this.persons`  not `this.data.persons`

```
remove(key) {
  console.log(key);
  this.persons= this.persons.filter(obj => obj.key !== key);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using filter?

```
remove(key) {
console.log(key);
this.persons = this.persons.filter(t=>t.key != key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your use case, if you trying to remove an item when it is clicked, you can (and should) use the index.  I see no reason to use a property.

Here is how I would remove an item base on an index:

```
<tr *ngFor="let person of persons; index as i" (click)="remove(i)">
  <td>{{person.key}}</td>
  <td>{{person.name}}</td>
  <td>{{person.email}}</td>
</tr>

remove(index) {
    this.data.persons.splice(index, 1);
}
```