# How to remove an element by considering the name of the element in string array in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a question about typescript. I want to remove an element by considering the name of the key value as follow. Let's take the array as follow

```
let myarr =[
    {
        name: "joe",
        age : 22
    },
    {
        name: "nick",
        age : 23
    },
    {
        name: "tom",
        age : 25
    }
]
```

I want to remove this part from the main array, by considering the name that `nick`

```
{
    name: "nick",
    age : 23
}
```

What I need to do this thing.

Comment: You speak about an array, but in code you have an object. Please make these things agree with each other, so that we'll be able to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove an element based on some property using typescript in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48456595/how-to-remove-an-element-based-on-some-property-using-typescript-in-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayNameHere = ArrayNameHere.filter((person) => person.name !== "nick")
```

Comment: What is `person`